# How can I get my first 10 rep point on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

I have to admit, for way too many years, I have been a passif user of stack over flow.

Until last week, when I saw an answer with a serious limitation. I had to throw in my comment on that one, it's really an easy fix... and then I hit a wall!

- Not enough point to comment. Requires: 50+

So I Google up on tips and trick on how to increase your rep but every single items requires 10+ to do.

So here I am, stuck at 1 rep point for completing my first badge.

What is the best way to get the **extra 9** rep point to get started at being a contributing member and to finally be able to comment on that answer that is ticking me.

Comment: You can edit posts to get points

Comment: Note: Edit requites 2000 rep point. see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: 2000 points lets you edit 'without it going through peer review'. I'm pretty sure you can edit before that but it gets peer reviewed.

Comment: Isn't the easiest way to get started with points to answer a question or two?

Comment: Just pick your edits wisely. Your first one ... don't bother about such non-questions, alteady closed or soon-to-be. The edit itself wasn't too impressive either.

Answer (score 6):

Start asking and answering questions.

Just by asking a question, someone in the community may give it an upvote if they find it relevant.

I've started answering questions when I'm free, and on a good day, I can get 50. Many people can probably get more points than me, but it's a start.

Comment: Precision: it seems that asking a good question is far more effective than answering questions in when you are starting. I have answered over 5 question previously and gave me zero point because those question did not spark enough interest.

Comment: "*I have answered over 5 question previously and gave me zero point because those question did not spark enough interest.*"  Yup. Depends on the viewer volume for the tags. If you look at most med-to-high rep users, you'll find most people have lots of answers with zero upvotes, including some very high quality answers.  **Just keep at it.** Rep comes over time.

Comment: For example, ~34% of my answers are zero-score answers. I've tried to write high-quality answers, but ultimately upvotes are for the community to decide. Don't sweat it.  Read [answer], do your best, and have fun.

Comment: I am sweat it over it anymore. as i got past the first 10 points. Just sharing my experience for others to be able to get pass the first 10 points.

Comment: in hind sight, this does not resolve the question. if the question is too easy, it get merged into an existing question like this one and you loose all your rep point. worse, it's a old question, so you need more points to comment 125. essentially you loose all means to find out how to level up.